# which is the library for java to send GCM push notifications?

Tags: java, google-cloud-messaging

i am trying to send the Push notifications from Java Server code. 
GCM api i am currently using is  com.ganyo's gcm-server api (v - 1.0.2)

it seems doesn't support the field "Priority" in Message object.

could someone please let me know which api i should use and it's maven dependency.

Answer (score 1):

The docs suggest [Java Smack library](http://www.androiddocs.com/google/gcm/ccs.html) both for upstream and downstream messages. They have a detailed example and code snippets that you can customize to fit your needs. Remember you don't necessarily have to use Java for server side but that is what they provided. Check it out. Good luck.